# Laravel API aren't reading access token from another server

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

I have 2 servers , an laravel API and an Auth server with passport. The authentication server generates the access token normally , i'm using client credentials.

When i try to protect my routes in API using the middleware `auth:api` or `client` , where it is defined on `Kernel.php` it returns me `401 Unauthenticated` the API dont read the token correctly.

My route in the API

```
Route::middleware('client')->group(function () {

    Route::resource('invoice' , 'InvoiceController')->middleware('scopes:x');

});
```

It returns 401, and the same route in Auth server works perfectly.

Comment: Are you using the same oauth keys for both servers?

Comment: Yes, for testing purposes. But the correct flow is: the Passport server generates the token and the API read it.

Comment: I meant the signing keys, the ones generated by `php artisan passport:keys`

Comment: Probably not , how i do that ? Use the same keys for the servers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokens are signed... with the Oauth keys... Use the same in both servers and that's all you need I think...

On one server you need keys... so

```
php artisan passport:keys
```

That generates the keys in the storage directory by default:
[image: Storage directory with encryption keys]

Then just copy those keys to the other server... the signature/encrpytion will then be the same in both servers...